# Git rename top-level project folder without messing up downstream

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repository which resides in `C:\dev\jenkins-1.501`. I want to move it to `C:\dev\jenkins-rpci` but not mess up anyone downstream of this repo. **Ideally, repos who have this repo as a remote should not see any changes to the files when they fetch**. The mv method does not work.

```
j@WI1DEV /c/dev/jenkins-1.501 (rename)
$ cd ..
j@WI1DEV /c/dev
$ git mv jenkins-1.501/ jenkins-rpci
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Edit: There is only one repo downstream of this right now. It has local modifications. If the solution requires setting a new remote, that is OK, but hopefully there is a way to do it without creating tree conflicts or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`git mv` is to move files within a repo.

you could symlink from the new repo location to the old location, but apart from that i don't see how you can solve it without updating the remote for the downstream repos.

Comment: Pointing to a new remote is OK. I don't want there to be a modified on every file or something like that after a setting a new remote though.

Comment: you can move the your repo (`origin` from the downstream's view) wherever you want, as long as you update `.git/config`  in every downstream and make the repective origin point to the new place. from gits point of view, that is all you have to change, nothing else.